# PHP - Как заключить ссылку в url с условием

Tags: php, wordpress

В шапке сайта выводится изображение сайта (`header_image`): на главной странице, в категориях и страницах статей. Нужно указать, чтобы на страницах статей выводилось изображение статьи, а не header_image. С условием, если у статьи имеется изображение, а если не имеется, то `header_image`.

Код вывода по умолчанию такой:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'oblique_header_style' ) ) :
    /**
     * Styles the header image and text displayed on the blog
     *
     * @see oblique_custom_header_setup().
     */
    function oblique_header_style() {
        if ( get_header_image() ) {
            ?>
            <style type="text/css">
                    .site-header {
                        background: url(<?php echo get_header_image(); ?>) no-repeat;
                        background-position: center top;
                        background-attachment: fixed;
                        background-size: cover;
                    }
        </style>
        <?php
        }
    }
endif; // oblique_header_style
```

И нужно как-то встроить в background url примерно следующий код:

```
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( get_theme_mod( 'post_feat_image' ) != 1 ) ) : ?>
    <div class="single-thumb">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'oblique-single-thumb' ); ?>
    </div>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Пробовал сделать так:

```
            if ( get_header_image() && is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) {
            ?>
            <style type="text/css">
                    .site-header {
                        background: url(<?php echo get_header_image(); ?>) no-repeat;
                        background-position: center top;
                        background-attachment: fixed;
                        background-size: cover;
                    }
        </style>
        <?php
        } elseif ( get_header_image() && is_single() )  { ?>
                <style type="text/css">
                    .site-header {
                        background: url(<?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'oblique-single-thumb' ); ?>) no-repeat;
                        background-position: center top;
                        background-attachment: fixed;
                        background-size: cover;
                    }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
    }
endif; // oblique_header_style
```

Но в таком виде на главной странице и категориях все остается по-прежнему. А на страницах статей вместо бэкграунда темный блок, будто не находит фото.

Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: background: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( 'oblique-single-thumb' ); ?>) no-repeat;

Comment: Нет, в таком виде все равно темное окно выходит

Comment: В стилях появляется ссылка  в свойстве  " .site-header { background: url() }"  ?  Зарегистрирован ли размер картинки "oblique-single-thumb" ?

Comment: Возможно он не может понять что от куда брать, в таком случае сделайте цикл или укажите параметр ID  в функции get_the_post_thumbnail_url();

Comment: Цикл: <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?><?php echo the_post_thumbnail(  POST_ID , SIZE  ); ?><?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: Если сохранить страницу в браузере и посмотреть код, то в категории, где появляется рисунок, написано:   <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
     <style type="text/css">
     .site-header {
      background: url(http://catacombs4.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-katakomby_007.jpg) no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
     }
  </style>
А на странице статьи, где рисунка нет: background: url() no-repeat; (т.е. пусто)

Comment: Вы можете смотреть свойства блоков или элементов в браузере нажав F12 или ctrl+shift+i или нажать "Просмотреть код" кликнув правой кнопкой мыши.

Comment: Как называется тема?

Comment: Тема Вордпресса "Oblique"

Comment: В категории, в анонсах код вывода рисунка статьи такой:  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( get_theme_mod( 'index_feat_image' ) != 1 ) ) : ?>
  <div class="entry-thumb">
   <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'oblique-entry-thumb' ); ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="thumb-link-wrap">
    <span class="thumb-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span>
   </a>
  </div>
 <?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'oblique_header_style' ) ) :
    /**
     * Styles the header image and text displayed on the blog
     *
     * @see oblique_custom_header_setup().
     */
    function oblique_header_style() {
        if ( is_single() && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( null, 'oblique-single-thumb' );
        } else {
            $img = get_header_image();
        }
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .site-header {
                background: url(<?php echo $img; ?>) no-repeat;
                background-position: center top;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
endif; // oblique_header_style
```

Comment: KAGG Design, так тоже не работает, темный фон вместо рисунка :(

Comment: Измените строку с функцией "get_the_post_thumbnail "  на "get_the_post_thumbnail_url" и код будет работать как нужно.

Comment: Оооо! Спасибо, Даниил! Заработало!

Comment: @Даниил да, совершенно верно.

Comment: @KAGGDesign  Внесите изменение в ответ.

Comment: @Alexandros Рад что вам помогло данное решение. Если ответ помог, будьте добры отметьте как правильный ответ.

Comment: @Даниил сейчас вернусь к компьютеру

Comment: Нажал на стрелку вверх в ответе @KAGGDesign. А ваш ответ как отметить? Я тут впервые

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос. У вас недостаточно баллов репутации, чтобы нажимать на стрелочки вверх или вниз возле ответа.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ок, отметил галочкой :)

Comment: "Для полного счастья" как бы еще указать в условии, чтобы при ширине изображения менее 1000px вместо нее загружался header_image? А то юзеры могут постить маленькие фото, которые в шапке (при автоматическом увеличении) будут неважно смотреться...

Comment: задайте новый вопрос, а то с учетом комментариев тут каша будет